# What is the correct way to detect true Boolean field in Django?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I would like to know if there is at least one isPinned = True for each user. Therefore, for the following schema I GROUP BY user_id and COUNT(isPinned=True).

```
Table STORY
-------------------
user_id    isPinned
0          True
0          True
0          False
1          True
1          False
```

This query achieves a semi-desired output:

```
Story.objects.values('user_id').annotate(pinnedCount=Count(Case(When(isPinned=True, then=1), output_field=IntegerField(),)))

[{'user_id': 0, 'isPinnedCount': 2}, 
 {'user_id': 1, 'isPinnedCount': 1}]
```

However, I would like SQL to stop needlessly counting after the first encounter with a True value to query faster.

Is ***counting*** the the correct database strategy to detect if at least one isPinned = True for each user?

Comment: Yes, but I actually do not care for the actual count. I would like to know if there is at least one isPinned = True for each user_id